# add floating point and integer and take absolute value

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, addition, absolute-value

Hello I am very new to code and I need to know how to output the value obtained by calculating |x+y| where x is a floating point and y is an integer, both unknown inputs. I have tried many things and cannot succeed please help me.

This is what I have now but I know it is very wrong :( In most cases when trying things I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`
This was my most recent attempt:

```
x = int(input())

y = input()

w = (x + y)

print (abs(w))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `y` to [float](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#float):

```
x = int(input())
y = float(input())
w = (x + y)
print(abs(w))
```

The function [input](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, from the documentation:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string